# Automation Testing - Checking of PDF content using WebdriverIO

Tags: node.js, pdf, automation, automated-tests, webdriver-io

I am currently working on with a test automation that focuses on verifying the data on a PDF file if it matches the data on my webpage and API using WebdriverIO with NodeJS.

I’m browsing for some resources but can’t seem to find a solution that suitable for the tool I’m using. I hope someone could help me. Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm packages `pdf-parse` or `pdfreader`.
For example:

```
// const { PdfReader } = require("pdfreader");
const pdf = require('pdf-parse');

module.exports = function data(filePath) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    pdf(filePath).then(function(data) {
      resolve(data.text)
    })
  })
}

// module.exports = function data (pathToPdf) {
//   return new Promise((resolve) => {
//     new PdfReader().parseFileItems(pathToPdf, (err, item) => {
//       if (err) console.error("error:", err);
//       else if (!item) console.warn("end of file");
//       else if (item.text) resolve(item.text);
//     })
//   });
// }
```